# Why is the Java bytecode instruction set not orthogonal?

Tags: jvm, bytecode

Section 2.11.1 of the [JVM 8 Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf) includes the words:

> In other words, the instruction set is intentionally not orthogonal.

From my perspective, that implies that the Java bytecode instruction set is full of dirty hacks.  I understand that the designers were restricted to only one byte to represent opcodes, but then they consumed 8 opcodes for aload and astore, not to mention individual opcodes for iload, fload, dload, etc.  The only reason I can think of for making the instruction set nonorthogonal is to optimize it for memory-constrained systems**; it seems these design decisions make it more difficult to write optimizers, not to mention limit the instruction set.

*Surely* I am missing something.  Why did the Java designers do it this way?

**When I say "memory-constrained", what I'm referring to is the size of the bytecode itself.  Presumably the reason they have aload_0 is because it saves a byte over aload 0, and it is used *a ton*.

Comment: Wasn't Java actually originally designed for embedded systems? (In the early-to-mid 90s, well before the advent of the Arduino and similar, those definitely qualify as memory-constrained!)

Comment: Hmm, seems like the word "orthogonal" is used incorrectly here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In the spec, or in my question?

Comment: @MasonWheeler That's the answer I was afraid of.  I guess I was hoping for a reason that was still relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Surely* I am missing something. Why did the Java designers do it this way?

Java grew out of [Oak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_%28programming_language%29), which was originally intended to be used in "smart appliances".  It was first developed in 1991.  So we're talking about old-school embedded systems, highly resource-constrained *by early 90s standards.*

Today, when "embedded system" can mean [a minimalist but full-featured computer that costs $9](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/05/move-over-raspberry-pi-this-startup-is-building-a-9-computer/), it seems a bit mind-boggling to architect a system that way, but almost 25 years ago, saving a byte here and a byte there on an embedded system was still a big deal.